# Chrome is now blocking Cognito tokens in localstorage within an iframe

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, iframe, amazon-cognito

This issue just started happening around mid-August 2023, and only to SOME of our users. I have an app that uses Cognito auth. The whole login process works completely fine when opened in a browser. When embedding that site in an iframe, the Cognito auth tokens are missing. I can have the iframe open and the site open in a separate tab side-by-side, the tab has the Cognito tokens, the iframe does not (found by inspecting localstorage). I could not find anything in the Chrome update notes that would have affected this functionality.

We have tried to reinstall and update Chrome. We have tried clearing all browser data. We have gone through change logs to find any updates that may have caused this. We have reduced all security settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be related with the localStorage partitioning that Chrome introduced in the last stable version, check out this link : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/storage-partitioning/
The localStorage of siteA is not anymore the same as the one in the iframe embedding siteA. If you are using chrome extension you can try to add host_permissions in the manifest.(https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/storage-and-cookies/#storage-partitioning)

### Solution

I managed to make my Cognito authentication work in the iframe by modifying the amplify configuration and adding **cookieStorage** settings in the configuration like so :

```
Amplify.configure({
Auth: {
  userPoolId: config.aws.userPoolId,
  userPoolWebClientId: config.aws.userPoolWebClientId,
  identityPoolId: config.aws.identityPoolId,
  region: config.aws.region,
  cookieStorage: {
    domain: config.host,
    path: "/",
    expires: 365,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
    partitioned: false
  },
  oauth: {
    domain: config.aws.oauth.domain,
    scopes: [
      ...
    ],
    redirectSignIn: config.aws.oauth.redirectSignIn,
    redirectSignOut: config.aws.oauth.redirectSignOut,
    responseType: "code" // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
  }
},
Storage: {
  bucket: config.aws.bucket,
  region: config.aws.region,
  identityPoolId: config.aws.identityPoolId
}
```

});

The part about `partitioned: false` tells amplify to not use the partitioning mechanism added in the latest stable of chrome which is activated by default.([partitioning in localStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YobM4.png))